# Python video decrease fps

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video, video-streaming

Quick question in regards to video editing in Python. Is there a way to decrease the frame rate of a video e.g. mp4 file. For instance I've got a video that is 25fps and I want to load it in and decrease the frame rate to 15.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Answer (score 4):

You could try and open this video with videocapture and modify it´s framerate with the set command:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("\file.mp4")
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 15)
```

From: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-decrease-the-frames-per-second-in-OpenCV-python

Comment: I tried this using files and links in VideoCapture but it never seemed to change my FPS.